# Register IUserStore<ApplicationUser> error using Simple Injector

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, simple-injector

Can someone help me with my problem in ASP.NET MVC? I am trying to register IUserStore in my system using the Simple Injector dependency.

At first, it gave me error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'The configuration is invalid.
>   Creating the instance for type ApplicationUserManager failed. The
>   constructor of type ApplicationUserManager contains the parameter with
>   name 'store' and type IUserStore<ApplicationUser> that is not
>   registered. Please ensure IUserStore<ApplicationUser> is registered,
>   or change the constructor of ApplicationUserManager.'

Upon searching, I found out that I should register IUserStore[ApplicationUser] to simple-injector.

```
container.Register<IUserStore<ApplicationUser>>();
```

However it's giving me error:

> System.ArgumentException: 'The given type IUserStore is not a concrete type. Please use one of the other overloads to register this type.
>   Parameter name: TConcrete'

I tried to find solution but none of those solution have help me. What should I do to solve this problem?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is Asp.net core or mvc5? For both version there are examples in the documentation for asp.net identity

Comment: See: https://simpleinjector.org/integration.

Comment: See: https://simpleinjector.org/aspnetcore#working-with-asp-net-core-identity